Oauth2 Login in spring using password grant type flow
can we do oauth2 login in spring application using password grant flow?
I checked the documentation and what I understand is, it uses authorization code grant flow to login? Is it possible to use password grant type to login in? any reference will be helpful.

Yes, you "can" set authorization-grant-type: password but using this flow is a worse practice. To me (and quite a few others), using it nowadays is even a professional misconduct.
According to the OAuth2 standard companion website:

The latest OAuth 2.0 Security Best Current Practice disallows the password grant entirely, and the grant is not defined in OAuth 2.1.

REST APIs should be configured as OAuth2 resource servers (which are not concerned at all with user login).
To consume a resource server from mobile & single-page apps, use the OAuth2 BFF pattern.

Thanks for the reply, I know it's not best practices but it my case I wants to do login in one of my application which uses oauth2 and through rest call I wants to login in that application. currently that application has implemented with authorization code grant flow , therefore I can not login in using rest call. does spring support to login in using password grant flow

As pointed out, its not even deprecated, its not allowed! You might as well not build any security at all.
